# Gelfand transformation of $l^p$

Tags: lp-spaces, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

I would like to describe Gelfand transofrmation of commutative Banach algebra $l^p(\mathbb{N}),p \in [1,\infty)$ with multiplication define by $(a_n)_n(b_n)_n=(a_n b_n)_n$, but I have no idea, how to do it. Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't seem like $l^p$ is closed under your multiplication operation.

Comment: @DanielSchepler It is closed - we consider space $l^p$, not $L^p$.

Answer (score 0):

The Gelfand transform in this case is nothing but the inclusion map $\ell_p\to c_0$ because the point-evaluations are the only non-zero characters on $\ell_p$.

Comment: we know, that $\Delta (l^p)=\{e_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ so then GT of $e_n$ is projection to n-th coordinate of $x\in l^p$ ...$\widehat{x}(n)=x_n$

Comment: the question is if there exist any other element of $\Delta(l^p)$

Comment: @lojdmoj, certainly not. Suppose that $f$ is a non-zero character. Then $f(e_n) = f(e_n)^2 \in \{0,1\}$. If $f(e_n) = 1 = f(e_m)$ and $n\neq m$, then $2 = f(e_n + e_m) =  f(e_n + e_m)^2$ because $e_n+e_m$ is an idempotent; a contradiction. Thus $f$ is a point-evaluation.

Comment: Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have got a question - why $2=f(e_n+e_m)$ holds ? We consider algebra only with multiplication.

Comment: @lojdmoj, but $f$ is linear...

Comment: Oh, sure. I am sorry, I am new in Banach algebra and I am little confuse. Thanks for help.