# $C_0(\Delta(l^p))$ description

Tags: lp-spaces, banach-algebras

If $X=l^p$ ,$p \in [1,\infty)$ is nonunitial Banach algebra with coordinate multuplication and $\Delta(l^p)=\{e_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $e_n(x)=x_n$ for $x \in l^p$, what is $C_0(\Delta(l^p))$ ?

Comment: This question is answered in a comment under my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062016/17929).